# Valid SSL without a domainmatch

Tags: ssl

that How is it possible that a domain like https://www.voo.st can use a SSL certificate that is issued for https://ssl2224.cloudflare.com (inspect certificate) without the browser given any warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certificate is valid for all the following names, present in the Subject Alternative Names extension:

```
DNS Name: ssl2224.cloudflare.com
DNS Name: *.logicsupply.es
DNS Name: voo.st
DNS Name: ctswholesalesunglasses.com
DNS Name: *.voo.st
DNS Name: *.synergistscada.com
DNS Name: synergistscada.com
DNS Name: wiihacks.com
DNS Name: *.wiihacks.com
DNS Name: vote4roberts.com
DNS Name: wallpaperweb.org
DNS Name: *.emphase.com
DNS Name: sintagoulis.gr
DNS Name: *.sintagoulis.gr
DNS Name: *.logicsupply.be
DNS Name: logicsupply.be
DNS Name: *.vote4roberts.com
DNS Name: nc-static.com
DNS Name: *.nc-static.com
DNS Name: *.ctswholesalesunglasses.com
DNS Name: logicsupply.es
DNS Name: *.wallpaperweb.org
DNS Name: emphase.com
```

Note that, in this case, the `CN=` RDN of the Subject DN shouldn't be used, but this doesn't matter since `ssl2224.cloudflare.com` is in both places anyway. See [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) for the validation rules (or RFC 6125):

> If more than one identity of a given type is present in the
> certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one of
> the set is considered acceptable.)

Answer (score 3):

Their Server Certificate uses subject alternative names (SANs) extension allows one SSL certificate to be used to secure one web server with multiple names such as different FQDNs, sub-domain names, internal IP addresses, and internal server names

Answer (score 1):

The SSL certificate on that server uses a `Subject Alternate Name` extension to give a list of (many) other domain names for which it is considered valid.

Answer (score 0):

This certificate is commonly referred to as a SAN certificate (Subject Alternative Name) also known as a UC certificate (Unified Communications Certificate). You learn more details here - http://www.ssl.com/subject_alternative_name